# Android Save Image from Custom Camera to Custom Folder on SD Card

Tags: android, image, file, save, android-camera

I have a custom camera that I would like to save the captured images from it on a folder in my sd card.  I've viewed a few examples, but for whatever reason I'm just not getting anything to save (folder or image).  Below is my code.  If anyone can help, that would be great!  I do already have the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE added to my manifest.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(CameraActivity.this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview); 
    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {   
        }
        return c;
    }
    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] datas, Camera camera) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            } 
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(datas);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  

            } catch (IOException e) {                
            }
        }

    };  

        private File getOutputMediaFile() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
            File myDir = new File(root + "/NewFolder/");  
            myDir.mkdirs();
            if (myDir.exists()){

            }

            Random generator = new Random(); 
            int n = 10000;
            n = generator.nextInt(n);
            String fname = "Image"+ n +".jpg";
            File file = new File (myDir, fname); 
            Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(file);  


            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
                    Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            i.putExtra("output", uriSavedImage);
            return file;

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have provided the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest.

On some phones file does not auto create when you write it from FileOutputStream so you can try this:

```
try {
                pictureFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(datas);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  

            } catch (IOException e) {                
            }
```

EDIT also on an unrelated note, The implementation of Random that you are using will always return the same number as the seed value is same. Try System.getCurrentMillis() instead for a unique name for your image.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  i did already have the permission written in my manifest, and I tried adding the pictureFile.createNewFile(); line in my code, but that still didn't do it.

Comment: Only thing i can suggest is updating the directory creation code to `File myDir = new File(root + "/NewFolder");  
            if (!myDir.exists()){
                myDir.mkdirs();
            }`
Notice the removal of the "/" at the end.

Comment: That didn't work either :(  Is it possible that I'm just formatting it all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you are having with saving images and our code are similar. I don't know if it matters but I am using an actual device. The thing that worked for me was to run the project on the phone, disconnect the phone from the computer, and test it. After testing, I can reconnect the phone to my computer and see if the image and folder are there. This did the trick for me and may be it can help you.